# How do I find the error message of an app that has become unresponsive in macOS?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-mac

I have a solution with many Azure Functions open in Visual Studio for Mac 2019. It works fine to code and run them. However, when I try to publish, then VS for Mac freezes completely and becomes unresponsive. My only option is to use force quit.

This happens every time without exception. No error message is shown.

I have a new Mac M1 and the latest version of macOS (11.2.1)

Without an error message, it is impossible to solve, so that is why my question is how do I find the error message when VS for Mac becomes unresponsive and is unable to show me any error message?

Comment: Sounds like VS Mac has crashed. If you look in the latest IDE log for VS Mac that may show the crash callstack - ~/Logs/VisualStudio/8.0/

Comment: Also you can run `kill -QUIT pid` from the Terminal window, replacing pid with the process id for VS Mac (from activity monitor). That will force VS Mac to log all the callstacks which may help diagnose the problem if this is a UI hang in VS Mac.

Comment: Side note: I did figure out the specific issue. I was publishing to an App Service that requires Zip Deployment and VS for Mac mindbogglingly does not support this. And does not even show an error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Status, Warnings and Errors that don't reach the user should show up in the Console,

```
open -a /Applications/Utilities/Console.app
```

[image]

Comment: Richard, I have checked the Console and it does not show any errors from Visual Studio. But it's definitely a good tip to look there as it may show up in other apps and scenarios.